# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in parallel computing

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I am trying to code an AMPI to sum a 1d array in parallel. However, I am getting a segmentation fault (core dumped).

I tried to fix my function so many times but I could not find where the error is or how to fix it.

```
/* File: mpi_sum.c
* Compile as: mpicc -g -Wall -std=c99 -o mpi_sum mpi_sum.c -lm
* Run as:  mpirun -n 40  ./mpi_sum
* Description: An MPI solution to sum a 1D array. */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int myID, numProcs;  // myID for the index to know when should the cpu start and stop calculate
                       //numPro numper of cpu you need to do the calculation
  double localSum;    // this for one operation on one cpu
  double parallelSum; // this for collecting the values of localsum
  int length = 10000000; // this for how many num
  double Fact = 1 ;
  int i; // this for for loop
  clock_t clockStart, clockEnd;   // timer
  srand(5); // Initialize MPI
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL); //Initialize MPI
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs); // Get size 
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myID); // Get rank
  localSum = 0.0;                               // the value for eash cpu is 0
  int A = (length / numProcs)*((long)myID);     // this is to make each cpu work on his area
  int B = (length / numProcs)*((long)myID + 1); // this is to make each cpu work on his area

  A ++;                                         // add 1 to go to next num
  B ++;

  clockStart = clock();                     // start the timer to see how much time it take
  for (i = A; i < B; i++)
  {
          Fact = (1 / myID - 1/numProcs) / (1 - 1/numProcs);
          localSum += Fact ;
  }

  MPI_Reduce(&localSum, &parallelSum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  clockEnd = clock();

  if (myID == 0)
  {
          printf("Time to sum %d floats with MPI in parallel %3.5f seconds\n", length, (clockEnd - clockStart) / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
          printf("The parallel sum: %f\n", parallelSum + 1);
  }

    MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to format the code in your question properly before anyone will even think about looking at it

Comment: Did you try using the debugger to narrow it down? You can't expect someone to read all this code and point it out to you. The debugger is the right way to narrow it down. You aren't allocating any dynamic memory, which is the common segfault issue novice C programmers encounter. The next candidate might be your MPI calls that pass addresses. You haven't shown the functions or at least the prototype headers for these function calls, so evaluation of whether there's a match in data types being passed cannot be done. You should confirm that.

Comment: Which version of MPI are you using ? Because the MPI_init might be the cause. Otherwise, why do you have a srand here ? You don't use any random number here. The documentation of MPI_init says to avoid doing thing before the initialization.

Comment: oh that my bad! I did it so fast and I am new to this website. thank you guys but still I am stuck and trying to fix it.

Comment: guys, I need help with the program please!!!

Answer (score 2):

When I ran your code, my numProcs came up as 1 and the program crashed with

```
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Floating point exception (8)
Signal code: Integer divide-by-zero (1)
Failing at address: 0x400af9
[ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10330)[0x7f8bb13d2330]
[ 1] ./mpi_sum[0x400af9]
[ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f8bb101af45]
[ 3] ./mpi_sum[0x400919]
*** End of error message ***
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

on the line

```
Fact = (1 / myID - 1/numProcs) / (1 - 1/numProcs);
```

because we had a zero in the denominator.

Since you are getting a different error, may I suggest putting in a bunch of:

```
printf("%d\n", __LINE__); fflush(stdout);
```

statements to get an idea where it is crashing?